# WordPress fullscreen menu with custom content and overlay

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I need help

I have been testing a lot of plugins to WordPress and try elaborate a fullscreen menu with custom content, but nothing works as desired and basically work as I expect

Does someone could help me? How can I make a this kind of menu? How to implement it in WordPress.

I was looking for the *wetransfer* menu, when we click on *nav* menu it opens until half page a menu with custom data/text/images and *nav* links.

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: you can add html and css in appearance/editor in Wordpress so you can code your own menu . try and add it to the post if you need some help

Comment: I have been searching w3schools i found this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp with this example i have css, html and js, where to i put all this code in wordpress , using divi thanks

Comment: can u add to the post the code of your mainpage or header ! (the code of the page where you want to edit the menu )

Comment: I want to edit the menu for the entire site

Comment: so you need to change in the header.php file

Comment: hello, thanks for your help and time. Sometimes a take a little long to come here, my 3 months baby thanks me a lot of time and attention... and capacity for thinking so i appreciate all the help.

what do i add to header.php? 

where to i add css and js ? 

Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Upload your .css .js files to your FTP server 
Second : include css files in the head tag of your header.php

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Third : include your javascript files :

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Finally drop the HTML code to the body :

```
<body>html code</body>
```